# How to get command line args of a process by id?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I have an ID of a running process (launched not by me). How can I get its command line arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use wmi to get this kind of info

```
var q = string.Format("select CommandLine from Win32_Process where ProcessId='{0}'", processId);
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q);
ManagementObjectCollection result = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject obj in result)
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", obj["CommandLine"]);
```

Comment: I found this shortened, simple, answer way better than anything listed on "recommended" link above. I got this small piece of code working fast.